# Default view inside UIViewController got warning because cannot find the outlet

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

Did anyone get this error? The default view inside UIViewController show an warning with this message: `"XXXViewController does not have an outlet named view"`. I have compare it with the others view controller and they don't got this error. Because of this error, I cannot set background color for view controller or add anything into it. Please see the image for the details.

[image]

Comment: Does your XXXViewController inherits from UIViewController?

Comment: Yes. It is. I figured out when I set the custom class of this xib file to UIViewController it doesn't show the warning. But when set custom class to my class it's show up the message.

Comment: control click on file owner and then connect the view reference to the view in the heirarchy

Comment: You are suppose to set the custom class for the viewcontroller and not the view. Could you please check if you are not accidentally changing class of the wrong component?

Comment: I can sure that I'm not changing class of wrong component. Just me see this problem, my team members are not. I asked them to change something in xib file like background color then push to git, but when update the new source it's still happened.

Comment: Okay. Then can you try removing the view reference outlet and add it back by control clicking on file owner

Comment: I tried. But it's cannot connect to the view: https://imgur.com/a/sqPna68